# Yii2 UrlManager w+ is not working for string

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I am trying to do url rewriting in Yii2 and for ids its working fine but for strings its not rewriting following is my code of main.php file in config.

```
    'urlManager' => [
                'class' => 'yii\web\UrlManager',
                // 'urlFormat'=>'path',
                             'enableStrictParsing' => true,
                    'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
                    'showScriptName' => false,
   'rules' => [

         '<page_id:\d+>'=>'site/page',
           //'<movie_id:[\w-]+>s'=>'site/genre',
           'genre/<movie_id:\w+>' => 'site/genre',
         '<alias:\w+>' => 'site/<alias>',
    ],
                ],
```

movie_id contains string characters too so I tried w+ but its not rewriting the url. Any help appreciated.

Comment: What is the string you want to process?

Comment: the string is the category of movie like New Release,Coming Soon etc and the string contains spaces which are converted to + automatically like this http://sitename.ca/genre?movie_id=Coming+Soon

Comment: Its working now with this regex expression [A-Za-z0-9 -_.]+ instead of w+ and is their any way that in url '+' should be replaced by hyphen or something

Answer (score 0):

Flag `\w` matches `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` so if you want to add `+` you need to modify it like:

```
<alias:[\w\+]+>
```

Comment: Its not working for me but [A-Za-z0-9 -_.]+ worked for me don't know the reason but thank you for help

Comment: You have put `.` there (dot) - not escaped dot = every character.

Comment: Sorry I didn't understood what you want to say and the expression which I used was producing some awkward behavior as my string contained spaces so i used your expression and but space in it and it worked like this '<movie_id:[\w\ +]+>s'=>'site/genre' and moreover without 's' in the end it is not letting me to render other pages. Do you know the reason for this